# Can I simplify tuple expression that uses a double reference?

Tags: rust, tuples, destructuring, mutable

I have an expression that creates variables that are double references, only to have to dereference the variable to use it in a call. I suspect there is a simpler syntax and way to call my function.

I have two types A and B, neither movable, but both cloneable. I am calling a function with a `Vec` of tuples of A and B and need to index the Vec to get out the tuple, destructure the values from the tuple into local variables, and use one value immutably but the other mutably in another function call.

```rust
  pub fn my_func(v: &mut Vec<(&A, &mut B)>, x: &mut C) {
    let i = 0_usize;        // Would be a loop index normally.
    let (a, b) = &mut v[i]; // This makes b a double reference.
    
    x.do_something(*b);     // This expects &mut B as parameter.
  }
```

How can I change the signature to `my_func`, the indexing of `v` and the destructuring into `a` and `b` in a consistent way to simplify things? Can I get away with fewer ampersands and `mut`s and derefs? Note that I do not need `a` to be mutable, just `b`.

Ignoring `&mut C` since it is required, if you count one point for each ampersand `&`, one point for each `mut`, and one point for each deref `*`, then you get 8 points. A solution that scores fewer "points" is a winner.

Comment: I would just advice to avoid tuple, tuple are unclear in this context, what is is ? Use named struct when you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to simplify the function's signature. You could replace `Vec<T>` with `[T]`, provided you don't need to push or pop elements from the vector, but this change doesn't affect the "score" per your definition.

Both `a` and `b` turn into double references because of [match ergonomics](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2005-match-ergonomics.md).

The pattern on the left side of the `let` doesn't have exactly the same "shape" as the expression on the right, so the compiler "fixes" it for you. The type of the expression is `&mut (&A, &mut B)`. The pattern doesn't match the outer `&mut`, so the compiler pushes it inside the tuple, giving `(&mut &A, &mut &mut B)`. Now the shapes match: the outer type is a 2-tuple, so `a` is `&mut &A` and `b` is `&mut &mut B`.

I've come up with a few variations on your function:

```
pub struct A;
pub struct B;
pub struct C;

impl C {
    fn do_something(&mut self, b: &mut B) {}
}

pub fn my_func_v1(v: &mut Vec<(&A, &mut B)>, x: &mut C) {
    let i = 0_usize;
    let (a, b) = &mut v[i];

    x.do_something(b);
}

pub fn my_func_v2(v: &mut Vec<(&A, &mut B)>, x: &mut C) {
    let i = 0_usize;
    let &mut (a, &mut ref mut b) = &mut v[i];

    x.do_something(b);
}

pub fn my_func_v2a(v: &mut Vec<(&A, &mut B)>, x: &mut C) {
    let i = 0_usize;
    let (a, &mut ref mut b) = v[i];

    x.do_something(b);
}

pub fn my_func_v3(v: &mut Vec<(&A, &mut B)>, x: &mut C) {
    let i = 0_usize;
    let (a, b) = &mut v[i];
    let (a, b) = (*a, &mut **b);
    // Or:
    //let a = *a;
    //let b = &mut **b;

    x.do_something(b);
}

pub fn my_func_v4(v: &mut Vec<(&A, &mut B)>, x: &mut C) {
    let i = 0_usize;
    let e = &mut v[i];
    let (a, b) = (e.0, &mut *e.1);
    // Or:
    //let a = e.0;
    //let b = &mut *e.1;

    x.do_something(b);
}
```

`v1` is identical, except I wrote `b` instead of `*b`. The compiler sees an expression of type `&mut &mut B` and a parameter of type `&mut B`, and will transparently dereference the outer reference. This might not work if the parameter type is generic (here, it's the nongeneric `&mut B`).

`v2` is the "direct" way to avoid making `a` and `b` double references. As you can see, it's not very pretty. First, I added `&mut` in front of the tuple, in order to match the type of the expression on the right, to prevent match ergonomics from kicking in. Next, we can't just write `b` because the compiler interprets this pattern as a move/copy, but we can't move out of a mutable reference and `&mut T` is not `Copy`. `&mut ref mut b` is the pattern version of a reborrow.

`v2a` is like `v2`, but with the `&mut` removed on both sides (thanks [loganfsmyth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/785065/loganfsmyth) for the reminder!). `v[i]` is of type `(&A, &mut B)`, so it cannot be moved, but it's an lvalue, so if we re-reference parts of it that cannot be moved/copied, then the whole thing won't be moved at all.

Remember that in patterns, `&mut` *deconstructs* a reference, while `ref mut` *constructs* a reference. Now, `&mut ref mut` might seem like a noop, but it's not. A double mutable reference `&mut &mut T` actually has two distinct lifetimes; let's name them `'a` for the inner lifetime and `'b` for the outer lifetime, giving `&'b mut &'a mut T` (`'b` is shorter than `'a`). When you dereference such a value (either with the `*` operator or with a `&mut` pattern), the output is `&'b mut T`, not `&'a mut T`. If it were `&'a mut T`, then you could end up with more than one mutable reference to the same memory location. `b` yields a `&'a mut T`, while `&mut ref mut b` yields a `&'b mut T`.

`v3` uses the dereferencing operator instead of `&mut` patterns, which is hopefully easier to understand. We need to explicitly reborrow (`&mut **b`), unfortunately; `*b` is interpreted as a move out of a mutable reference, again.

When `b` is `&mut &mut B` and we pass either `b` or `*b` to `do_something`, neither of these two are actually "correct". The correct expression is `&mut **b`. However, the compiler automatically references and dereferences arguments (including the receiver) in function/method calls, but not in other contexts (such as the initializer for a local variable).

`v4` saves a couple `*` by relying on the auto-deref from using the `.` operator.

Comment: Wow. The semantic graph of automatic ref/deref actions is one I have not yet internalized. This is very helpful.

Comment: I went with v2a. It consolidates the messiness into one place.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to explicitly declare the `b` binding to be a reference into `v[i]` directly. This can be done with

```
let (a, ref mut b) = v[i];

x.do_something(b);
```

For simplifying the signature, you're pretty limited, but one place to start would be

```
pub fn my_func(v: &mut [(&A, &mut B)], x: &mut C) {
```

assuming your function doesn't actually try to add/remove items in the vector.

Comment: This still makes `b` a double reference. You'd need to write `let (a, &mut ref mut b) = v[i];`. That said, I forgot `v[i]` is an lvalue, which makes `ref mut` work without causing a "move out of index" error (compare with `let e = v[i];`, which causes such an error).

Comment: @FrancisGagné Won't it auto-deref either way? Both `x.do_something(b as &mut B);` and `x.do_something(b as &mut &mut B);` appear to compile. (Ah now saw your edit)

Comment: I explain this behavior in my answer.